# Creating folder names executes forever and not creating all folders using while loop?

Tags: python

I'm trying to download all the images for each race from this [site](https://www.f1-fansite.com/f1-wallpapers/).

As you can see the list has duplicates. I'm trying to create a folder for each item in the list.
I am aware that the list contains duplicates.
My current implementation runs forever, and only creates 14 folders.

I'm not too sure what exactly is going on.

**How do I create the folder names for EACH item in the list?**

```
#25 items including duplicates

['f1', 'canadian', 'azerbaijan', 'azerbaijan', 'monaco', 'monaco', 'spanish', 
'spanish', 'miami', 'miami', 'romagna', 'romagna', 'australian', 'australian', 
'arabian', 'arabian', 'bahrain', 'bahrain', 'season', 'season', 
'car', 'season', 'f1', 'season', 'car']
```

What I have tried:

```
def create_folders(folder_names):
    name = folder_names #25 items

    index = 0

    while index < len(name):
        item = name[index]
        for name in item:
            curent_dir = os.getcwd()
            check_dir = os.getcwd() + "/" + str(name)

            if not os.path.exists(check_dir):
                os.mkdir(curent_dir+ "/" + str(name))

            SAVE_FOLDER = curent_dir + "/" + str(name)
        index+1
```

Result of current implementation:
[coderesult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ioii.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might find the following approach a bit better:

```py
import os

def create_folders(folder_names):
    curent_dir = os.getcwd()

    for folder_name in folder_names:
        os.makedirs(os.path.join(curent_dir, folder_name), exist_ok=True)

create_folders([
    'f1', 'canadian', 'azerbaijan', 'azerbaijan', 'monaco', 'monaco', 'spanish', 
    'spanish', 'miami', 'miami', 'romagna', 'romagna', 'australian', 'australian', 
    'arabian', 'arabian', 'bahrain', 'bahrain', 'season', 'season', 
    'car', 'season', 'f1', 'season', 'car'
] )
```

It uses [`os.makedirs()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=os%20mkdir#os.makedirs) which can also work with folder names that already exist. [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html?highlight=os%20path%20join#os.path.join) will safely create a path from a list of path elements so you don't need to worry about adding path separators.

If you wish to create a unique folder name for all entries, a digit could be added when there are entries with the same name:

```py
from collections import Counter
import os

def create_folders(folder_names):
    curent_dir = os.getcwd()

    for folder_name, count in Counter(folder_names).items():
        if count == 1:
            os.makedirs(os.path.join(curent_dir, folder_name), exist_ok=True)
        else:
            for index in range(count):
                os.makedirs(os.path.join(curent_dir, f"{folder_name}_{index+1:02}"), exist_ok=True)
```

This would give folders such as:

`season_01` `season_02` or just `canadian`

Comment: Very elegant solution. But this still doesn't address the duplicate folder issue. The list has duplicate names, but the above implementation only creates folders for half

Comment: It would help if you showed your expected output. Do you want `spanish` then `spanish2` ?

Comment: Your above solution is ideal. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you just forgot the '=' sign, you need to do `index+=1` when you increment index

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your code you're not properly incrementing the `index` value, that's why you are stuck in a infinite loop.

```
def create_folders(folder_names):
    name = folder_names #25 items

    index = 0

    while index < len(name):
        item = name[index]
        for name in item:
            curent_dir = os.getcwd()
            check_dir = os.getcwd() + "/" + str(name)

            if not os.path.exists(check_dir):
                os.mkdir(curent_dir+ "/" + str(name))

            SAVE_FOLDER = curent_dir + "/" + str(name)
        index += 1
```

Refactor the last line of your function and change it to `index += 1`, in order to avoid the infinite loop and to make it work properly.